# How to autofill/autopopulate profile forms?

Tags: profile, webform-civicrm

I created a public profile form with fields First Name, Last Name, email, and I'd like those fields to be auto-filled when a contact is logged in.

I thought it was supposed to do this by default, but it does not seem to in both the official demo Civicrm or my local.

Here is a link to a public profile I created on the CiviCRM, but this link will die when the demo site resets.  http://d45.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/profile/create?gid=15&reset=1

Comment: bdombro can you update this question with your CiviCRM version and CMS and version? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue is purely to do with your URL - you have the 'create' link - which is intended to provide an empty set of fields.

If you change to http://d45.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/profile/edit?gid=15&reset=1 you should see the data pre-filled

Comment: nw. thanks for coming back and updating this.

Answer (score 0):

Install the webform-civicrm module if you're on Drupal. Add a new webform in Drupal. Use Existing Contact for the user who will log in, in the CiviCRM tab. The user's existing info will show on the form. The user can update her own info.

If the user is also entering or updating data for another contact already in CiviCRM, create contact 2 in the CiviCRM tab for the webform, and use Existing Contact for contact 2 for the logged in user (contact 1) to be able to  look up contact 2's existing info. Contact 1 can update contact 2's info, or add a new contact.